# Using readline in Node.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, if-statement, input, readline

I'm trying to use `readline` inside an else if statement:

```
var rl = readline.createInterface({
    input: process.stdin,
    output: process.stdout
});

rl.question("Would you like to see which cars are available? Please type yes/no: ", function(answer) {

    if (answer === 'yes') {
    // if yes do something
    } else if(answer === 'no') {
        rl.question("Would you like to search by latitude or longitude instead? If yes, please type latitude and longitude: ");
    } else {
        console.log("No worries, have a nice day");
    }

    rl.close();
});
```

What is the correct way to ask the user a different question if the user types 'No'?

Currently, if the user types No, the second question does not get asked.

Comment: I'm just wondering if you learnt what was wrong with your code since you accepted an answer that doesn't actually answer your question?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

If I were to do this I would start by making a promise based version of the readLine question function:

```
const question = (str) => new Promise(resolve => rl.question(str, resolve));
```

And I would structure it as a set of steps:

```
const steps = {
  start: async () => {
    return steps.seeCars();
  },
  seeCars: async () => {
    const seeCars = await question("Would you like to see which cars are available? Please type yes/no: ");
    if (seeCars === 'yes') { return steps.showCars(); }
    if (seeCars === 'no') { return steps.locationSearch(); }
    console.log('No worries, have a nice day');
    return steps.end();
  },
  showCars: async () => {
    console.log('showing cars');
    return steps.end();
  },
  locationSearch: async () => {
    const longlat = await question("Would you like to search by latitude or longitude instead? If yes, please type latitude and longitude: ");
    return steps.end();
  },
  end: async () => {
    rl.close();
  },
};
```

If you're new to async functions note that you have to type `await` before your question to instruct node not to proceed until the question resolves with an answer.

Also note that whenever we change steps you need to `return` so that the rest of the step doesn't run.

Here is the complete program for you to copy and play with:

```
const readline = require('readline');

const rl = readline.createInterface({
  input: process.stdin,
  output: process.stdout,
});

// Create a promise based version of rl.question so we can use it in async functions
const question = (str) => new Promise(resolve => rl.question(str, resolve));

// A list of all the steps involved in our program
const steps = {
  start: async () => {
    return steps.seeCars();
  },
  seeCars: async () => {
    const seeCars = await question("Would you like to see which cars are available? Please type yes/no: ");
    if (seeCars === 'yes') { return steps.showCars(); }
    if (seeCars === 'no') { return steps.locationSearch(); }
    console.log('No worries, have a nice day');
    return steps.end();
  },
  showCars: async () => {
    console.log('showing cars');
    return steps.end();
  },
  locationSearch: async () => {
    const longlat = await question("Would you like to search by latitude or longitude instead? If yes, please type latitude and longitude: ");
    return steps.end();
  },
  end: async () => {
    rl.close();
  },
};

// Start the program by running the first step.
steps.start();
```

Comment: Thank you so much this is what I needed!! I'm fairly new to async functions but your example has helped in my understanding of using them

Answer (score 1):

The rl.prompt() method writes the readline.Interface instances configured prompt to a new line in output in order to provide a user with a new location at which to provide input. Using setPrompt when the user typing 'no' to ask the different question.

```
const readline = require('readline');
let lastAnswer = '';
const rl = readline.createInterface({
    input: process.stdin,
    output: process.stdout,
    prompt: 'Would you like to see which cars are available? Please type yes/no: '
});
rl.prompt();
rl.on('line', (line) => {
    switch (line.trim()) {
       case 'yes':
           lastAnswer = 'yes';
           console.log('great!');
           rl.setPrompt('Would you like to see which cars are available? Please type yes/no: ');
           break;
       case 'no':
           if (lastAnswer === 'no') {
               lastAnswer = '';
               rl.close();
           }
           lastAnswer = 'no';
           rl.setPrompt('Would you like to search by latitude or longitude instead? If yes, please type latitude and longitude: ');
           break;
       default:
           lastAnswer = '';
           console.log(`Say what? I might have heard '${line.trim()}'`);
           break;
    }
    rl.prompt();
}).on('close', () => {
    console.log('Have a great day!');
    process.exit(0);
});
```

Comment: Thank you for your example, but if if the user types No for the second question, the statement will re ask the user the same question (latitude/ longitude),  how can I allow the user to exit if he types in No twice?

Comment: you can use a variable saving the last answer, see my updates in the code.

Answer (score 0):

The `question` function requires a callback function otherwise it is ignored. 
So all you need to do to fix your problem is to add a callback function to the 
 `rl.question` because that's the only way to get the answer and you want to know the answer right?

```
rl.question('...?', function(){});
```

https://github.com/nodejs/node/blob/master/lib/readline.js#L270

From Node.js source:

```
Interface.prototype.question = function(query, cb) {
  if (typeof cb === 'function') {
    if (this._questionCallback) {
      this.prompt();
    } else {
      this._oldPrompt = this._prompt;
      this.setPrompt(query);
      this._questionCallback = cb;
      this.prompt();
    }
  }
};
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are not married to the readline package, [Inquirer][1] is a very nice npm library that supports use of promises. E.G.

```
var inquirer = require('inquirer');
inquirer.prompt([
  {
    type: 'confirm',
    name: 'whichCar',
    message: 'Which car do you want to drive?'
  }
]).then(function(response) {
   if (response.whichCar === true) {
      // do your thing
   } else { 
      // do your second prompt
   }
})
```

If you must used readline, then the above users have explained very well how the callbacks need to work. If not, then I think inquirer is a strong option with lots of flexibility and customization.
[1]: https://www.npmjs.com/package/inquirer/v/0.3.5